# How to add comments through the SoundCloud API

Tags: objective-c, macos, api, soundcloud

I would like to post comments via the SoundCloud API but looking at the [documentation](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) it seems impossible, the only method available for `/tracks/{id}/comments` seems to be `GET`. When I try to send it a `POST` I get a `HTTP Error: 422`, same happens if I use the console I get a 422 too, with `"error_message": "Body can't be blank"` even so I added `body=test` as a parameter.

Any idea how you are supposed to add a comments via the API?

I can see that it seems to be possible with for example the ruby SDK:

```
# create a new timed comment
comment = client.post("/tracks/#{track.id}/comments", :comment => {
  :body => 'This is a timed comment',
  :timestamp => 1500
})
```

but I am using the Objective-C SDK and this is my code so far (which returns a 422):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:content forKey:@"body"];
if (timestamp >= 0)
{
    [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", timestamp] forKey:@"timestamp"];
}

NSString *resource = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tracks/%i/comments", trackId];

[scAPI performMethod:@"POST" onResource:resource withParameters:dict context:delegate userInfo:nil];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I was able to find it out on myself, I had a look at the Java version and its examples:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new java.util.ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment[body]", "This is a test comment"));

HttpResponse response = api.post("tracks/" + TRACK_ID + "/comments", params);
```

So the strange decision to not only have `body`as the key but `comment[body]` and without documenting it in the API was what I had problems with. I tried to do it like the ruby version suggested do have a `NSDictionary` with the key `comment` and within another one with `body` and `timestamp` but that would just cast errors because the SDK didn't expect nested dictionaries. So now the code looks like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:content forKey:@"comment[body]"];
if (timestamp >= 0)
{
    [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", timestamp] forKey:@"comment[timestamp]"];
}

NSString *resource = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tracks/%i/comments", trackId];

[scAPI performMethod:@"POST" onResource:resource withParameters:dict context:delegate userInfo:nil];
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a great music app which allows you to connect favorably with Amazon's latest music, videos, and movies while freelancing other products as well.

Comment: Where is the link? Even with a link, this should still be a comment, since it doesn't answer the question.