# SoundCloud API Failing on track comment

Tags: c#, api, soundcloud

I am trying to consume SoundCloud API in .NET application. I need to post a comment for a predefined track. I am using the following code:

```
byte[] response = client.UploadValues(String.Format
("https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/{0}/comments.json?oauth_token={1}&comment={2}",
trackID, token, txtComment.Text), "PUT", new NameValueCollection()
{
    { "body", "Comment" }
});
```

I receive The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
The result is the same when I use soundcloud console http://developers.soundcloud.com/console.

Do I miss something? Or is there another way to post a comment to a track using the API?

Comment: The API requires a `POST` request if I'm not mistaken to post comments.

Comment: The result when using POST is The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution of my issue. It is here: 
[How to add comments through the SoundCloud API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768474/how-to-add-comments-through-the-soundcloud-api?rq=1)

My code should look like this:

```
byte[] response = client.UploadValues(String.Format
("https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/{0}/comments.json?oauth_token={1}&comment={2}",
trackID, token, txtComment.Text), "POST", new NameValueCollection()
{
    { "comment[body]", "Comment" }
});
```